# TypeError: $ is not a function (Magnific Popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, typeerror

I'm a newbie to web dev, so please stick with me. I know this question has come up a lot (or a similar deviation), but after a couple of hours of searching I have not found an answer that works for me.

I've made sure the JQuery file is loaded first, and tried multiple versions to no avail. Whenever I try to load the Magnific Popup script, I get (TypeError: $ is not a function) on line 50. I've had a look and tried to change $ to JQuery to no avail, so it's back to normal now.

Here's the Magnific Popup code block:

```
var mfp, 
    MagnificPopup = function(){},
    _isJQ = !!(window.jQuery),
    _prevStatus,
    _window = $(window), <<<<<< ERROR HERE
    _document,
    _prevContentType,
    _wrapClasses,
    _currPopupType;
```

And the relevant html:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Press "$" on console, and see if it returns a fucnction.

Comment: script tags are inside body tag...? should be in head .. right

Comment: @tariq - Can you justify your claim? Is it somehow illegal to have scripts inside body?

Comment: @Amit its not a standard practice...

Comment: @tariq - It's valid HTML, and sometimes it can actually help avoid "FOUC" style behavior

Comment: @Amit of course its valid HTML, just taking about specifications

Comment: @Callum the information provided is not enough to gauge the cause..

Comment: @Amit, No problem, I'll now delete all my comments, so the topic stays clean

Comment: The code is enough to gauge the cause, because that's all there is. I got frustrated and transferred it to a small html file to help with debugging. 
@NevinMadhukarK this was my response function JSTH_$()

However Sreejiths solution worked for me, only leaving a warning

Comment: @CallumBond - I think the problem was that your `src` attribute had an illegal address. You could either add the "http" (like NevinMad...) or omit the "//"

Answer (score 1):

looks like its not picking your jquery library from CDN..

make sure that you have the network in your system or have access to jquery CDN url

if all above is fine then you try with http in CDN url like below.  this is working for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, I encountered the same issue but it was not that I did not include jQuery, but that I included it after I included the magnific-popup code.  Once I put it above the magnific-popup include, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your jquery file from your own (local) machine. Hopefully, this will work well.
Also, it would be helpful for me if you please let me know that you are not getting `404` for the JQuery file from the CDN.